# issue with pd.read_csv in hadoop streaming

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, streaming

I am new to Python, trying to read data from hadoop streaming.

Here is my python code, `var_list = get_config()` is working fine.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        var_list = get_config()
        dat = pd.read_table(lines,delimiter=',',header=0)
        #print (dat)
        print (dat.dtypes)
        #print (dat['var8'])
```

Here is the file that i am passing, having first line as headers.

```
$ cat data
client_id,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8
121,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
112,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
102,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
121,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
125,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

when i try printing the dat.dtypes, here is the output.

```
$ cat part-00000
1   int64
102     int64
2   int64
3   int64
4   int64
5   int64
6   int64
7   int64
8   int64
client_id   int64
dtype: object
dtype: object
var1    int64
var2    int64
var3    int64
var4    int64
var5    int64
var6    int64
var7    int64
var8    int64
```

My problem is it is not reading data properly, What could be the issue?

I did try with `pd.read_csv` also, and it is giving me the same issue when i read data with `pd.read_table`.

I was executing the hadoop streaming like this.

```
hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.0-mapr-1602.jar -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=opsistg_q1 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx40960m -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=25000 -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=25000 -Dmapreduce.task.timeout=180000000 -mapper "<local path>/config_mapper.py" -input "<hadoop location>/data"
```

Comment: understood the problem, here sys.stdin read data line by line, That should be the problem. So, Now any idea, who to read sys.stdin and place line by line to some buffer place or file?

Comment: Please paste your code, data, and output as text instead of using images.

Comment: @Khris please check now

Comment: Hm, when I copy your data and use `pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')` the data is read correctly. Same for `pd.read_csv`. You need to add more info about the way you're reading your data. Could be an issue with newline characters or encoding.

Comment: @subro are you saying the types are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code for this.

## Mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    toks = line.split('\001' ,2)      
    ck=toks[0]+toks[1]               
    others=toks[2]           
    print '%s\t%s'%(ck, others)
```

Takes data from stdin, splits it and emit it as key(ck)-value(others) pair.

## Reducer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    ck_others = line.split('\t')          # parsing mapper o/p 
    ck = ck_others[0]                     
    others = ck_others[1]                
    
    other_parsed = others.split('\001')
```

This parses mapper output as well as splits value(`others`) as well.